Xcode 15.4 always popup to click "Trust and Open" when open workspace
I just upgrade my macOS from Monterey to Sonoma. And then I also downloaded and installed the new XCode version 15.4. I'm also git clone my project from my BitBucket repo after upgraded to macOS Sonoma.
The issue started when I opened my project workspace after clone the repo. I always popup "" is a workspace downloaded from the Internet. Are you sure you want to open it? Opening, building, or running a project containing malicious code can harm your Mac or compromise your privacy. Be sure you trust the source of the project before opening it."

Once I click "Trust and Open" btn, it open the workspace file normally. However, after close the XCode and open the project workspace again, it displayed the same popup.
Does anyone have any idea how to remove this popup.
Thank you ^_^

Apple provides Gatekeeper, if the app wasn't properly signed, the warning would be different - "[ExampleApp] is from an unidentified developer" or "[ExampleApp] is damaged and cannot be opened."
Thus, the fact that you're seeing "[ExampleApp] is an application downloaded from the Internet" is typical and indicates that your app is correctly signed.
This warning is the same one users will encounter when downloading any application from the internet. For instance, if you download Google Chrome, you'll see the identical message.
If you want to remove this warning still you can check this post
